# Как прописать путь к файлу в Pig?

Tags: bash, csv, hadoop

Путь к файлу создан с помощью bash:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p user/result/`date +%Y`/`date +%m`/`date +%d`
```

файл будет находится в последней папке:

```
hdfs dfs -put table.csv user/result/`date +%Y`/`date +%m`/`date +%d`
```

теперь вопрос: **как правильно прописать путь к файлу в Pig скрипте, если каждый день будет создаваться новая папка с названием дня месяца - `date +%d`?** То есть каждый день нужно будет извлекать файл из новой папки.
Следующий вариант не сработал:

```
A = LOAD user/result/`date +%Y`/`date +%m`/`date +%d`/table.csv as (f1:chararray);
```

Answer (score 1):

обычно в таких случаях делают *symlink* на актуальный файл/каталог.

приблизительно так:

```
$ d=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d')
$ mkdir -p $d
$ ln -snf $d actual
```

и получается такая картина:

```
$ tree
.
├── 2015
│   └── 11
│       └── 03
└── actual -> 2015/11/03

4 directories, 0 files
```

теперь по имени `actual` (произвольное) можно обращаться к содержимому каталога `2015/11/03`.

а завтра после выполнения тех же команд *symlink* `actual` будет указывать уже на каталог `2015/11/04`.

---

в применении к вашему частному случаю, как я понимаю, должно выглядеть примерно так (вместо `actual` я использовал имя `last`):

```
$ d=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d')
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p user/result/$d
$ ln -snf user/result/$d user/result/last
$ hdfs dfs -put table.csv user/result/last/
```

---

**обновление**

прочитал комментарии к [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13408921/4827341) — да, в *hdfs* нет *symlink*-ов.

тогда, вероятно, имеет смысл сохранять требуемый путь в файле. или только локально, или (в дополнение) там же, в *hdfs*. что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
$ d=$(date +'%Y/%m/%d')
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p user/result/$d
# сохраняем «переменную» часть пути в локальный файл last
$ echo $d > last
$ hdfs dfs -put table.csv user/result/$d/
# сохраняем локальный файл last в hdfs
$ hdfs dfs -put last user/result/
```

при необходимости получения сохранённого файла, делаем *get*:

```
$ hdfs dfs -get user/result/last last
```

и читаем содержимое файла `last` в переменную:

```
$ d=$(cat last)
```

которую затем можно использовать для адресации:

```
$ hdfs dfs -get user/result/$d/table.csv table.csv
```

Comment: а что делает ln -snf команда?

Comment: программа `ln` создаёт *symlink*-и и *hardlink*-и. по поводу опций — посмотрите `man ln` на предмет использованных опций: `-s`, `-n`, `-f`.

Comment: локально всё работает, но в hdfs папка, к примеру, "last" не создаётся,

Comment: добавил обновление.

Comment: я тут подумал, что будет проще создать отдельную временную папку, туда переместить файл, а после завершения процесса просто её удалить. я просто новичок в bash, и выглядит всё это немного запутано для меня

Comment: если по каким-то причинам не подходит текущий каталог (как в приведённых мнью примерах), конечно, можете использовать любой другой (куда у вас есть право записи).